# Ajustar código a la ventana en Atom

Tags: atom-editor

¿Saben cómo puedo hacer para que el código se ajuste a la pantalla y no se desborde en Atom?

En VScode sé que es con Alt + z, pero en Atom cuál será la combinación de teclas o el lugar en el que se habilita?

Answer (score 1):

Por si a alguien le interesa, logré resolverlo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En **View** seleccioné la opción **Toggle Soft Wrap**